# How to stop IntelliJ from changing my ">=" Operator to this. Because it is a bad habit I think

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHR4r.png)

I need to know how to change settings, so that i will be able to write as well as see the >= operator as it is. Because if I'll see this operator every day, i might not remember in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Preferences / Settings | Editor | Font* or *Preferences / Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Color Scheme Font* and disable *Enable ligatures* option.

[image]